# How the proper way to transform object key array to normal object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to convert the posters object below to the normal array of objects but my code is not looking best any way to convert it proper in TypeScript.

and I don't know what a poster's object structure is called?

```
const posters = {
  facebook: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  twitter: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  instagram: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  youtube: null,
  forum: null,
};
```

If some entity has null value will be not returned to the new object, an object will be like this.

```
const posterTransformed = [
  { platform: 'facebook', name: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] },
  { platform: 'twitter', name: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] },
  { platform: 'instagram', name: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] },
];
```

And this is my code

```
const transformPosters= (posters: any) => {
  const results = [];
  if (posters?.facebook)
    results.push({ platform: 'facebook', name: posters?.facebook || [] });
  if (posters?.twitter)
    results.push({ platform: 'twitter', name: posters?.twitter || [] });
  if (posters?.instagram)
    results.push({ platform: 'instagram', name: posters?.instagram || [] });
  if (posters?.youtube)
    results.push({ platform: 'youtube', name: posters?.youtube || [] });
  return results;
};
```

Comment: `Object.entries(posters).filter(([k, v]) => v).map(([k, v]) => ({ platform: k, name: v }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional approach for transforming the entries which have a non-null value:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2BATgg8gIwFZQLxQBKEAxnCgCYA8SKAlgHYDmANFLY0wNoC6UAPlAYBXADaiAfAG4AUDNCRYiZCnxQA3jKhQwogIbAAZuQC2ALnbB6zWdoZ6TECx2a9ZAX1kzDwhiWB0cAxQVnoMCMYoJlBUACpQEAAeyAwUCEpIqBg4EgAUYMpZFrEAlBbwmSi8GlpQZOHAUCgQCGLA5YVVfARuctqRULn1SFBcugaRJmz2jnxwhlBY2KTAAHQQDFZ0LfmdCCUlNdradAu5AIQAgigoeiCrdAjXtyC5MxAHdUEBIhC2x81WqI1mBhAgABa5dTjIymaYOCDuEr-dx9JoQYDCFDBQFtDxyYaNAqVdIETT9PQkCCYOBwADWFi4AHI9KymWwmZgueyoEySPymTwWLVgAB3OjAFSMllsjlczA8vkCoW1RhIPRMW7mUYyvSK+WK-kkQXC7QgODCTGYJxCMSiU1QSLCbUicTCzwEoIjXHAtShcKTXYk5EyYZwUQQVaiOBMXI+4AhgD0ACoZFxauooAAiGGTLMWLOGSnU2l0rNsLPvfOjLOsvTl7PyhtZo1ZvjuB2ZnP6WFRatZsUSlTNquM2us5tNiut9ud7O50z9tXADVakcI6tccf1itT7MzqCongyZOJoA)

```ts
type PostersObj = Record<string, string[] | null>;

type Poster = {
  platform: string;
  name: string[];
};

function transform <T extends PostersObj>(posters: T): Poster[] {
  const result: Poster[] = [];

  for (const [platform, name] of Object.entries(posters)) {
    if (!Array.isArray(name)) continue;
    result.push({platform, name});
  }

  return result;
}

const posters = {
  facebook: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  twitter: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  instagram: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  youtube: null,
  forum: null,
};

const result = transform(posters);
console.log(result);
/*
[
  { "platform": "facebook", "name": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] },
  { "platform": "twitter", "name": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] },
  { "platform": "instagram", "name": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) when I need to loop over something and omit some values in the result. I might try something like this:

```
const transformedPosters = Object.keys(posters).reduce((acc, currentKey) => {
  const value = posters[currentKey];
  if (value && value.length) {
    acc.push(
      {
        platform: currentKey,
        name: value
      }
    )
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(transformedPosters)

// output 
[
  { platform: 'facebook', name: [ 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' ] },
  { platform: 'twitter', name: [ 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' ] },
  { platform: 'instagram', name: [ 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' ] }
]
```